# Access control forces me to have fixed routes

Tags: security, symfony, routes, symfony-2.1

What's the point in having flexible routes (being able to change routes without breaking the application, thanks to route identifiers like 'admin_settings' -> '/admin/settings') if then in security.yml, in access_control we have to specify the paths (instead of the ids)?

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/test, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/reset, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/settings, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Every time I change a route I will have to check that it is still secured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I have same problem, so I write little extension for symfony security.yml that adds route names support, maybe you will be interested: https://github.com/madesst/MadesstSecurityExtraBundle

You will be able to write in this way:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:    '@*' # Equals to '^/' in old syntax
            anonymous:  ~
            form_login:
                login_path:  '_demo_login'
                check_path:  '_security_check'

    access_control:
        - { path: '@my_bundle_post_delete', roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
        - { path: '@my_bundle_post_*', roles: ROLE_USER}
        - { path: '@my_bundle_post', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/esi, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
        - { path: ^/esi, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```